# How to center a header image

Tags: css, image, center

I have a problem. The answers to other people questions didn't solve my problem.

It's about image in my header, here's the code:

HTML

```
<div id="site">

    <div id="header">
        <img class="center" src="http://i.imgur.com/jfDhpP5.png"/>    
    </div>

    <div id="mainNav">
        <li><a href="#">one</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">two</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">three</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">four</a></li>
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
#container{
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}

#header{
    display: block;
    width: 1000px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

body{    
    background-color: grey;
    color: black;
    font-family: sans-serif;
}

img.center{
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding:0px;
}
```

I also try this:

```
div#pictures {
  text-align: center;
}
```

also not working... checked in firefox and IE, the newest versions.... o.O

Please help!

Comment: Seems fine: http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5wr3v/

Comment: are you sure #site div is centered?

Comment: seems fine a your link. But on my computer, it still goes bad :/. Can't figure out why.  Its always left align.

Answer (score 9):

CSS for `header`

```
width:100%;
text-align:center;
```

CSS for your `img`

```
display:inline-block;
margin: 0 auto;
```

[See example here](http://jsfiddle.net/2hB9Z/)

That said, merely having `text-align:center;` on your `header` should be find, [as in here](http://jsfiddle.net/UYjG6/)

Comment: Okey, it was about wrong attaching the css file. Wrong name in <link> ...

Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

To add to SW4's answer, there are various ways to align text with CSS.

```
div.a {
  text-align: center;
}

div.b {
  text-align: left;
}

div.c {
  text-align: right;
}

div.d {
  text-align: justify;
}
```

For anyone looking for a great, getting started resource, one I'd recommend is [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_text-align.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to SW4's answer I was having a similar problem with a header image. I was using a rectangular image and also trying to make it circular. After fixing the image shape and sizing I then had an issue with getting centered in the .

Here's my code...

HTML:

```
<div class= "image-cropper">
<img src="#" class="profile-pic">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-cropper {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display:inline-block;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.profile-pic {
  display: inline;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-left: -15%; /*centers the image*/
  height: auto;
  width: 250px;
}
```

-- somebody may have a better way of coding it out but after several attempts and messing around with the px and % I finally got mine to look the way I intended.