# How do I get the header in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

Trying to get the header and images under it right in the middle of the page but am having a lot of trouble figuring out how to do that. Tried manipulating the box model with no luck. I'm really new to this stuff so any advice helps.

[image]

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition:all 1s;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  min-height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Choose Your Weapon</h1>
    <div class="container">
      <img src="images/rock.svg" alt="rock">
      <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="paper">
      <img src="images/scissors.svg" alt="scissors">
      <p></p>

    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think your problem has been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20149206/how-to-center-a-header-image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) for this

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose Your Weapon</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img src="images/rock.svg" alt="rock">
  <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="paper">
  <img src="images/scissors.svg" alt="scissors">
  <p></p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Choose Your Weapon</h1>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="images/rock.svg" alt="rock">
    <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="paper">
    <img src="images/scissors.svg" alt="scissors">
    <p></p>

  </div>
  <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is `positioning` and use of property `left, top` which even hide `top text` when you reduce screen size, instead you can change it's `position` to `relative` and then use `margin` to align that at `center` of page,

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition: all 1s;
}

.container {
  position: relative;
  min-height: 400px;
  background: red;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Choose Your Weapon</h1>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="rock">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="paper">
  <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x100" alt="scissors">
  <p></p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this can be done by a dirty little trick i learned when i started. Before i get to that, i would like to make some changes to your code:

A) No need for setting `position: relative;` for body because all the elements automatically move in relation to the body of your page. Setting the position to relative means that you are confining the position element of everything inside the body as `relative`. So it will ignore the `absolute` of the `.container` class.

B) Second, i don't see a reason why if you want to keep the header and the images together, you do not keep them under a single class. It makes it easier to move them around together rather than shifting one by one.

Now to the trick, for starters, you need to set the `min-height`and `min-width` 
of the container class in *pixels*. Once you have done that, you can position the class at the middle by:

```
top: 50%;
left:50%;
margin-top: -200px; /*half of the height of the container*/
margin-left: -200px; /*half of the width of the container*/
```

So, now your code, all summed up must something like this:

```css
body {
  background: radial-gradient(gold, goldenrod);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

img {
  padding: 10px;
}

img:hover {
  transform: scale(1.4);
  transition:all 1s;
}

.container {
  position: absolute;
  min-width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  top:50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}
```

```html
  <body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Choose Your Weapon</h1>
    
      <img src="images/rock.svg" alt="rock">
      <img src="images/paper.svg" alt="paper">
      <img src="images/scissors.svg" alt="scissors">
      <p></p>

    </div>
    <script>
    
    </script>
  </body>
```

and guess what, it's even responsive :)